# Query executed successfully but inserted other data in table

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database table named "tasks".
I executed below query in phpmyadmin.

```
INSERT INTO tasks 
VALUES (' ',17,'Test Task','Test Task descriptions','0', '1','','0','', '1','2014-3-20','1','2014-3-15','NOW()' ) ;
```

The query is executed successfully but other data is inserted to the table eg I have provide title "Test Task"  but there inserted `"werwr"`

What could be the problem?

Comment: That's not your problem, but i think you expect to place current DateTime into last column, not string 'NOW()', so remove single quotes

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to define columns explicitly, so you query should look like:

```
    INSERT INTO table1 (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`) VALUES (value1, value2, value3)
```

or

```
    INSERT INTO table1 SET `col1` = value1, `col2` = value2, `col3` = value3
```

Other way if you change table structure in future, you might get unexpected results.

That's might happen in your case, you expect to insert one value, but insert another.

You might have problems with encoding

And last thing, your values might be truncated

Answer (score 0):

***your doing some mistake in sql query. And, you should must mention the `field name`you should insert following format:***

```
INSERT INTO TASK (FIELDNAME1,FIELDNAME2,FIELDNAME3,...)
VALUES (VALUE1,VALUE2,VALUE3,..);
```

Comment: @Pushpendra Singh, look at my answer